# I have 2 tables I am looking to join, with no common column, but the information is needed

Tags: sql, oracle, join, between

I need to return the name and salary grade of each employee.
I have two tables, Employee and Salgrade.

Employee is set up this way -

```
    CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
   (EMPNO NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    ENAME VARCHAR2(10),
    JOB VARCHAR2(9),
    MGR NUMBER(4),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    SAL NUMBER(7,2),
    COMM NUMBER(7,2),
    DEPTNO NUMBER(2),
    PRIMARY KEY (EMPNO),
    FOREIGN KEY (DEPTNO) REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO));
```

and we want the employee name (ename) and the related grade from this table

```
      CREATE TABLE SALGRADE
     (GRADE NUMBER NOT NULL,
      LOSAL NUMBER,
      HISAL NUMBER,
      PRIMARY KEY (GRADE));
```

I wanted to wright a full outer join to combine them. from there i'm not sure how to take the number from sal in employee and have it calculate using between losal and hisal to output grade. taking the grade outpute and throwing it into a view.

or something like this.

create or replace view namesal as
select employee.ename, employee.sal, salgrade.grade, salgrade.losal, salgrade.hisal
from employee, salgrade

then some how creating a query to determine what grade for each sal an employee has.

the data -

```
    Rem ***** enter data into EMPLOYEE *****

    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'),800,NULL,20);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1600,300,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,500,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2975,NULL,20);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,1400,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2850,NULL,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2450,NULL,10);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('13-JUL-87')-85,3000,NULL,20);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),5000,NULL,10);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1500,0,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-JUL-87')-51,1100,NULL,20);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),950,NULL,30);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),3000,NULL,20);
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES
        (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-yyyy'),1300,NULL,10);


    Rem     ***** enter data into SALGRADE *****

    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (1,700,1200);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (2,1201,1400);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (3,1401,2000);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (4,2001,3000);
    INSERT INTO SALGRADE VALUES (5,3001,9999);


    Rem ***** commit the changes to the database ******

    COMMIT;
```

Comment: I removed the inappropriate database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `full outer join` does not seem like the right solution.

Just use inequality in the `JOIN`:

```
select e.*, sg.grade
from employee e left join
     salgrade sg
     on e.sal between sg.losal and sg.hisal;
```

This is just like the joins you learned about, except the condition is not `=`.  Note:  this assumes that `losal` and `hisal` are inclusive.

This is a *left* join so all empoyees are in the output.  I see no reason to include salary grades that have no corresponding employees.  But if you really like, you can make this a `full join`.

Comment: The OP asked for a full outer join. Here's hoping it's not [mysql]

Comment: Yeah the number and to_date give it away

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is perfect! Thank you.
for the Sg and the E in salgrade sg and employee e, Is that giving it a synonym sort of thing so you just refer to the short letter form rather than typing it out every time?

Comment: @Ambrotus . . . Yes.  Those are called table aliases.

Comment: @ConradFrix . . . For me, it is `VARCHAR2()`.